# Is there any Terraform code or ARM Template code available for enabling diagnostic settings in data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-diagnostics

I am able to enable diagnostic settings manually in the portal,If i want to automatically create diagnostic settings for data factory through code, is there any terraform code or ARM template code available to do this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with this `ARM template` and successfully enabled diagnostics settings.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
  {
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
    "name": "Deploy_DataFactoryDiagSettings",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "resourceGroup": "YourResourceGroupName",
    "properties": {
      "mode": "Incremental",
      "template": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {},
        "variables": {},
        "resources": [
          {
            "type": "microsoft.datafactory/factories/providers/diagnosticsettings",
            "name": "{YourADFresourceName}/Microsoft.Insights/ADFDiagSetting",
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
            "properties": {
              "name": "ADFDiagSetting",
              "storageAccountId": null,
              "eventHubAuthorizationRuleId": null,
              "eventHubName": null,
              "workspaceId": "/subscriptions/{YourSubscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{YourResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{workspaceID}",
              "logs": [
                {
                  "category": "PipelineRuns",
                  "enabled": true,
                  "retentionPolicy": {
                      "enabled": false,
                      "days": 0
                  }
                },
                {
                  "category": "TriggerRuns",
                  "enabled": true,
                  "retentionPolicy": {
                      "enabled": false,
                      "days": 0
                  }
                },
                {
                  "category": "ActivityRuns",
                  "enabled": true,
                  "retentionPolicy": {
                      "enabled": false,
                      "days": 0
                  }
                }
              ],
              "metrics": [
                {
                  "category": "AllMetrics",
                  "timeGrain": "PT1M",
                  "enabled": true,
                  "retentionPolicy": {
                    "enabled": false,
                    "days": 0
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "outputs": {}
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
  }
],
"outputs": {}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks you @NiharikaMoola-MT,It helped alot to solve my problem